# How to write a parser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

In our product we are trying to parse the following different formats from a given piece of text -

1. `${{node::123456}}`
2. `${{node:123456}}`
3. `$fn{{#functionName('abcd',',','  somethingWithASpace')}}`
4. `$fn{{#functionName('abcd','#','${{node::123456}}')}}`
5. `${{rmtrqst:someText[]->abcd}}`

Sample of the text is like -

1. `Hi, how are you ${{node::123456}}? Your order id is ${{node::636636}}.`

or

2. `Your order was placed on $fn{{#dateConverterFunction('abcd','#','${{node::123456}}')}}`

I tried with Regex `/\$((fn)\{{2}(\#|)(\w*)((\(.*\))|([^\$]*))\}{2})/gi` - but this is not helping much. Can anyone suggest me how to write a parser for this?

A grammar could be like this -

1. Every expression starts with $ followed by either fn{{ or {{
2. After that there will be a string like node or #functionName or something else
3. that might be followed by a parenthesis enclosed string (this may contain the whole expression like ${{node::1234}} inside it - we should ignore whatever inside parenthesis
4. Finally it will be closed by }}

Comment: The first step would be to define a grammar. This is heavily underspecified.

Comment: The grammar could be like this -
1. Every expression starts with `$` followed by either `fn{{` or `{{`
2. After that there will be a string like `node` or `#functionName` or `something else`
3. that might be followed by a parenthesis enclosed string (this may contain the whole expression like `${{node::1234}}` inside it - we should ignore whatever inside parenthesis 
4. Finally it will be closed by `}}`

Comment: I doubt that a single regex is going to work in all possible cases here.  You might just start by a simple regex to isolate ${{}} and then parse whatever is inside it...

Comment: "A string like node" is again by far not specific enough. What characters? Can function calls be nested, ...

Comment: @IngoBürk - no function calls are not nested - 'a string like node' means `${{node`

Answer (score 3):

Use a tokenizer and let it break the strings down to a meaningful structure.

The [nearly.js](https://nearley.js.org/) library is a popular choice for parsing non-linear structures like yours. You can choose to keep your expressions simple - or, if choose otherwise, the library can create an abstract syntax tree for complicated grimmer.

To write a parser using the library, define your vocabulary in a seperate file and use it for parsing.

Or you can directly using the tokanizer to get your string tokanized.

```
@{%
const moo = require("moo");

const lexer = moo.compile({
  ws:     /[ \t]+/,
  number: /[0-9]+/,
  word: /[a-z]+/,
  times:  /\*|x/
});
%}

# Pass your lexer object using the @lexer option:
@lexer lexer

# Use %token to match any token of that type instead of "token":
multiplication -> %number %ws %times %ws %number {% ([first, , , , second]) => first * second %}

# Literal strings now match tokens with that text:
trig -> "sin" %number
```